# Silverlight: Make ListBox big enough to fit all content?

Tags: silverlight

I have a `ListBox`  with enough items that it makes a vertical scrollbar visible. How can I make the list box automatically grow in height so it can display all items at once, without scrolling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that at the core of the `ListBox` template is this Xaml:-

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}">
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

The ScrollViewer makes what you want to do quite difficult.  The solution is to (assuming you really need a **ListBox** specifically) is to re-template the ListBox.  Adjust the above portion of the template to:-

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ItemsPresenter />
</Border>
```

You would probably want to use `StackPanel` as the items panel as well.

However if you don't need the selection features of ListBox then a simple ItemsControl would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure it's container will give it enough space.  If the container for the `ListBox` is a `Grid` with fixed width and height then it will give the `ListBox` a fixed size.  When the height of the items exceeds that size then the scroll bar will become visible.  If you put the `ListBox` in a `StackPanel` the `StackPanel` will give the `ListBox` infinite size.  You still have to make sure the size of the `StackPanel` is unbounded though.